# SQL Count query on how many fields have another field with a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a log table that has includes columns named IP and ID in SQLSERVER

Now some IP's share the same ID and what I need to do is get a result set back that gives me a count of how many distincts IP's where found for each ID.  This one has me a little fooled at the moment can anyone please help

so if I have

```
IP           ID
129.168.0.2, 12
192.168.0.3, 12
1292.68.0.3, 1
```

I want a result set that shows

```
COUNT, ID
2,     12
1,     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `group by` clause with a `distinct` for the IP:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IP), ID FROM table1
GROUP BY ID
```

Otherwise, you would be counting all the IPs instead of the unique ones.

Comment: I tried that and it come back with invalid as IP is not contained in either and aggregate function or the group by clause.  Add IP into the group by and I get counts of 1 and rows containing the distinct IP and ID combinations.  Unfortunately that was the first type of query I tried before asking the question.

Comment: You are doing something wrong: Here is a working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9d0e/1)

Comment: select count (DISTINCT kpl.dbo.PrintLogs.IP), kpl.dbo.PrintLogs.IP, kpl.dbo.PrintLogs.LicenseID from kpl.dbo.PrintLogs group by kpl.dbo.PrintLogs.LicenseID  This is the query actually under Microsoft SQL Server Mangement studio on a SQLEXpress instance for development purposes

Answer (score 1):

You can use [aggregate function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function).

Try this:

```
select count(distinct IP), ID from table1
group by ID;
```